# How to extract value of a state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

While using multiple state variables in my `App.jsx` I wanted to set the value of one state equal to that of another state.

```
const [exchangeRatio, setExchangeRatio] = useState();
const [toCurValue, setToCurValue] = useState();

function foo()
{
   setToCurValue(exchangeRatio);
}
```

On console.log(exchangeRatio);

```
{exchangeRatio: undefined}
exchangeRatio: undefined
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

On further

```
console.log({exchangeRatio}.valueOf());
>>Undefined
```

I am new to React if there are ways to do the same feel free to write.

Comment: If the 2nd state has the value of the 1st state then why do you even need two states?

Comment: They can be different as well it's just one particular scenario where i want them same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [exchangeRatio, setExchangeRatio] = useState();
const [toCurValue, setToCurValue] = useState();
```

The above statement denotes that you are declaring a state with values stored in `exchangeRatio` and `toCurValue` respectively and those states can be modified only using `setExchangeRatio` and `setToCurValue` methods respectively.

While you declare a state using `useState()`, you are expected to specify the initial value of the state inside the `useState()` as a parameter. For eg. if you want the initial value of `exchangeRatio` to be 10, then you must write it as -

```
const [exchangeRatio, setExchangeRatio] = useState(10);
```

Now, since you haven't provided an initial state value, you are getting the console logged output as undefined. Once, you properly initialize it with the proper value, you can directly use the state and the stored value will be returned to you.

---

So, suppose you want to set `toCurValue`'s value to be equal to `exchangeRatio`'s value (which has been initialised properly), then you can either do it while writing useState() or using the `setToCurValue` in following ways -

```
const [toCurValue, setToCurValue] = useState(exchangeRatio);
```

OR

```
setToCurValue(exchangeRatio);
```

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't working because I had not initialized the state.